# Cómo puedo implementar este Algoritmo-pseudocódigo en Python 3?

Tags: python, pseudocódigo

Este es el algoritmo que debo implementar en python , se trata de un Algoritmo de ordenamiento MergeSort ,pero por más que intento pasarlo a Código en Python no me sale , alguna idea ? Podrían compartir la solución ?
El Algoritmo está en la imagen

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5hNQ.jpg)

Comment: Publica el código como texto, no como imagen, y menos con un link a un sitio externo.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?